# UpdatePanel in SharePoint throws an error

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-ajax

I get the following when I click on a custom made webpart in the Web Part Gallery: `The control with ID 'UpdatePanel1' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.` If I use the webpart, ie perform a search, I get a pop-up error: `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The Status code returned from the server was: 500`.

This webpart takes a search string from a textbox, passes it to BL/DAL and returns a data from DB. I've integrated an UpdatePanel for partial postbacks - used [this blog](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/mike/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=3) as guide  but it is not working.

I've added the scriptManager to the `default.master` page using MSSP Designer as the blog suggests but curiously, the script manager causes an error (red underline) `In Internet Explorer 6.0 the tag <asp:ScriptManager> is not permitted.`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not totally sure what's up with that but here's an alternative.  Dont use MS Ajax - EVER.  jQuery is simpler, faster, better, stronger, sexier!

This is how I normally do this stuff:

1. add jQuery to your master page head
2. create a user control that implements your web part ui.  This should use Page.ScriptManager.RegistryScriptInclude or .RegistryScriptBlock to insert script for the control.  Eg, methods to do your callback using jQuery.Ajax.
3. create a web part wrapper for the user control
4. create an aspx in _layouts that acts as the 'service' for your callback.  The page load can use the parameters passed from the ajax call to return some json or text

Instead of #4 you could create a web service but this is a lot harder with SharePoint - an apx will work well enough.

HTH

Cheers